# chrome extension in angular 2/4 chrome.history not binding to modal

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I am tryin to build an chrome extension in angular2, part of it will display users chrome history. The component:

```
/// <reference types="chrome/chrome-app"/>
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { mockHistory } from  './chrome-history-mock';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chrome-history',
  templateUrl: './chrome-history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chrome-history.component.css']
})
export class ChromeHistoryComponent implements OnInit {
  historyData: any = [];
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    var microsecondsPerWeek = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
    var oneWeekAgo = (new Date).getTime() - microsecondsPerWeek;
    chrome.history.search({
     'text': '',
      'startTime': oneWeekAgo,
      // 'maxResults': 10
    }, this.constructHistory);
  }
  constructHistory(historyObj): any {
    console.log(historyObj[0]);                     //prints first obj
    this.historyData = historyObj;
    console.log(this.historyData.length);           //prints 100
    console.log(historyObj);                        //prints data
    console.log(JSON.stringify(historyObj));        //prints data
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.historyData));  //prints data
  }
}
```

The template:

```
<ul  *ngIf="historyData?.length > 0">
<li *ngFor="let item of historyData | async">
  <div class="history-item"><input type="checkbox" />{{item.title}}</div>
  <span class="history-url">{{item.url}}</span>
</li>
```

I am getting the response inside callback function constructHistory and am able to set it to class property historyData as I can see in console logs, but this doesn't display in template. I've tried to find the answer for more than 3 days. Searched a lot many blogs but couldn't find any solution. Most were about databinding in http.get case. Also tried async pipe but couldnt solve. Sorry about the code formatting. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't know TS but I doubt constructHistory preserves `this` when invoked as a callback of chrome API. Most likely it defaults to `window` object.

Comment: I was able to find the solution after some fiddling. It was a syntax fix. Instead of this.constructHistory, I used (data) => { this.historyData = data; } .